# T-SQL End of Month sum

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with some transaction fields, primary id is a CUSTomer field and a TXN_DATE and for two of them, NOM_AMOUNT and GRS_AMOUNT I need an EndOfMonth SUM (no rolling, just EOM, can be 0 if no transaction in the month) for these two amount fields. How can I do it? I need also a 0 reported for months with no transactions..
Thank you!

Comment: You already tried a select with group by and sum? Did you looked up the books online for Month and year functions?

Comment: I did, I have had a difficulty calculating this, I am now working on the trick of making a list of all months first day and then subtract one and find the last day of previous month, but can't make it work..

Comment: If you can add that effort to your question that will prevent early closing of your question

Comment: @Nick an interesting "quirk" of sql is, if you `dateadd(month,1,'2013/01/31')` - you get the last day of February 2013 (leep year aware) and if you `dateadd(month,2,'2013/01/31')` you get the last day of March 2013, etc.  You can use this to calculate the last day of any month (using `year()` and `month()` to get back to the January for a given date). HTH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you [group by](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) the expresion  [month(txn_date)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187813%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) you can calculate the [sum](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx). If you use a temporary table with a  join on month you can determine which months have no records and thus report a 0 (or null if you don't use the [coalesce](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) fiunction).

This will be your end result, I assume you are able to add the other column you need to sum and adapt for your schema.

```
select mnt as month 
, sum(coalesce(NOM_AMOUNT ,0)) as NOM_AMOUNT_EOM
, sum(coalesce(GRS_AMOUNT ,0)) as GRS_AMOUNT_EOM
from (
  select 1 as mnt
  union all select 2
  union all select 3
  union all select 4
  union all select 5
  union all select 6
  union all select 7
  union all select 8
  union all select 9
  union all select 10
  union all select 11
  union all select 12) as m 
left outer join Table1 as t
     on m.mnt = month(txn_date)
group by mnt
```

Here is the initial working [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7c298/8)

Comment: a bit pedantic, I know, but `union all` is going to be infinitesimally less costly - but will significantly simplify the execution plan (making further analysis and optimization easier for OP).  Am I the only one that thinks `union` should default to `all` and force a user to specify `distinct` if they want it to sort/dedupe?

Comment: @dav1dsm1th not at all pedantic. The execution plan is indeed much better now. Tnx.

Comment: This is indeed impressive and almost what I am seeking for. May I ask, how to include [id] and two amounts in the output? I mean, I have the table as you design it, with my primary key being 3 fields, like [id1] [id2] and the [txn_date] and I have 2 amount fields, like, amt1 and amt2. Can I adjust the logic above to accommodate this?

Comment: You cann't have the primary keys in it but you can add another sum